# How do cancel an operation(unzip) in a few seconds in Python?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Some files do not know what they are from have long extract
For example, if it is not extracted for 60 seconds or the time is passed, I want to delete the original file to cancel the operation.

```
import pyzipper
with pyzipper.AESZipFile('test.zip', 'r', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_LZMA, encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as extracted_zip:
    extracted_zip.extractall(pwd=str.encode("@apkclub"))
    os.remove(test.zip)
```

Comment: Instead of using `extract_all`, you could enumerate the files one by one, and only unzip those smaller than a certain size.

Comment: The problem I have is not the file size
It is related to some files

Comment: Unzip time is directly proportional to file size.  Right?

Comment: I know what you mean
But for example, I extract a few files with a size of 200 MB. Maybe one of the compressed files has a problem and its extraction takes a long time. I just want to set a timer to cancel it after 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through files inside the archive and read them in chunks. I didn't test this code but the correct solution could be close to:

```py
import os
import time
import pyzipper


CHUNK_SIZE = '4096'

zip_fname = 'test.zip'

try:
    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(zip_fname, 'r', compression=pyzipper.ZIP_LZMA, encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as zip_file:
        for filename in zip_file.namelist():
            start_time = time.time()
            with zip_file.open(filename) as file_in_archive:
                with open(filename, 'w+') as extracted_file:
                    while (chunk := file_in_archive.read(CHUNK_SIZE)):
                        extracted_file.write(chunk)
                        if time.time() - start_time > 60:
                            raise Exception('too long')
except Exception as error:
    print(error)

os.remove(zip_fname)
```

You may want to implement more sophisticated logic in handling the timeout situation.